# Django menu & childmenu from models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to a menu system for my sport site project where the sports are grouped together. For example the main category would be "ballsports" and under that (the child menu) people would select football, baseball or whatever else. I've got that all setup and functioning but I can't workout how to call the child menus into the templates.

**Models:**

```
class Sport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    sport_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Sport_Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
class Sport_Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    category_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
```

**Views:**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name="sports/index.html"
    context_object_name='all_sport_category'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Sport_Category.objects.all()

    def list_of_sports_in_category(self):
        sport_cat = self.category.name
        return sport_cat

class SportListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name="sports/sport-home.html"
    context_object_name='sport_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Sport.objects.all()
```

**Template:**

```
{% for sport_category in all_sport_category %}
  <li>{{ sport_category.name }} </li> *(Working)*
  {% for sports in list_of_sports_in_category  %}
    hi
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `list_of_sports_in_category` is not passed to the template context. So in the template that will be empty. In class based views, custom methods will not actually do anything unless you specifically use them in some other defined method.

Comment: I believe that `{% for sports in sport_category.sport_set.all %}` is what you are looking for.

Comment: That works, thank you very much. Quick follow up question, if I need to create a custom method when using a class based view I need to I need to use that method within one of the methods that come with the class based views, correct?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. It's not trivial to add custom functionality to class based views. This site might help you understand the inheritance tree. http://ccbv.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list_of_sports_in_category method seems to return the category name, rather than the list of sports. try replacing the second for-loop in your template with {% for sport in sport_list %}.

Comment: Thats how I had it at first but it didnt work. Though I have just noticed, even when it isnt nested inside "for sport_category in all_sport_category" it isnt returning anything.

Comment: What if you try this in place of the second for-loop:  {% for sport in sport_category.sport_set.all %} {{ sport }} {% endfor %}

Comment: Yep, that worked on the main page, but now it isnt extending properly throughout the other pages. I havent come across this in my other starter projects yet. The base.html file is extending okay, but the for-loop isnt.

Comment: Could be because the context variable "all_sport_category" is defined in the index view. What if you try to replace it in the for-loop with "sport_category.objects.all"?

Comment: That's exactly what's causing the problem, but that didn't work. I think I need to create a view just for the menu to make it work across all the pages?

Comment: I think it would be better to create a custom context processor. See this blog post: https://matthewphiong.com/django-global-template-variable

Comment: My apologies. This is the updated procedure: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/

Comment: Thank you! I had to dig into the source code on github to workout exactly how to put it in, but once I did imported the models and called "categories" into the for-loop and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much :D